# How to toggle click an element to show or hide the other element?

Tags: jquery, click, document

when i click `.foo` area , `.bar` will show.
when i click `document` area , `.bar` will hide.
But i don't know how to do when i click `.foo` area to make `.bar` hide.

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) this [article](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/), so i don't want to use `event.stopPropagation()`in my code because it is dangerous.

```js
$('.foo').click(function() {
  $('.bar').show()
})

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
 
    var _con = $('.bar'); 
    if (!_con.is(e.target) && _con.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
      $('.bar').hide();
    }
  
});
```

```css
.foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by 2 way, if the first approach is not working the second might work. Please have a look and test.

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
$('.bar').toggle();
});


//2nd approach
$('.foo').click(function(){
var bar = $('.bar');

if(bar.css('display') == "block"){
    bar.css('display', 'none');
}else{
    bar.css('display', 'block');
}

});
```